# Jenkinsの拡張をこれからはじめて実施したいと考えています。

Tags: jenkins

一般的にJenkinsやHadsonを拡張する場合のワークフローを教えてください。はじめてなので、どのように進めればよいかがよくわかっていません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 個人的にはこれは興味深い質問です。クローズでなくてもいいのではないかと思ったので、メタで投稿しています。
 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2582/754

Comment: 拡張というのはプラグインを自作したいと言うことでしょうか。Jenkins/Hudsonの構築運用と、Javaによるプログラミングについてどの程度のスキルがあるのでしょうか。公式のドキュメントや、Web上にもプラグインの作成について解説する記事がそれなりにあるようですが、それらについてどのぐらい調べられていて理解度はどの程度なのでしょうか

Comment: @suzukis そうです。ご指摘の通り、Web上でよく調べてみると、プラグインの作成方法を書いた記事が見つかりました。調査不足で質問してしまい申し訳ありません。また進める過程で不明な点が出てきたらここで質問したいと思います。ありがとうございました。